# How to check whether EnableViewStateMac is set at runtime?

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.NET, the ViewState is typically protected from tampering on the client with a signature generated by the machine secret on the server.  But this protection can be easily turned off with:

```
<%@ Page ... EnableViewStateMac="false" %>
```

I'm writing an ASP.NET control that *may* store security-sensitive information (not secret... but it must not be tampered with), depending on whether EnableViewStateMac is true.

How can I test to see whether it's on or off at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to reference

```
Page.EnableViewStateMac
```

From within your code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstatemac.aspx

Comment: Wow.  This just goes to show that if something doesn't exist in Intellisense, some developers don't think it exists at all.  It's a perfect spot for that property to go, and yet that property has `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` set on it so that Intellisense doesn't expose it.

Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can check using this.Page. EnableViewStateMac

Note from the above [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstatemac.aspx)

Do not set this property in code. Set the EnableViewStateMac attribute using the @ Page directive in the .aspx file. When the page is requested, the dynamically generated class sets the property.

---

A view-state MAC is an encrypted version of the hidden variable that a page's view state is persisted to when the page is sent to the browser. When this property is set to true, the encrypted view state is checked to verify that it has not been tampered with on the client.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to note that as of September 2014

All versions of the ASP.NET runtime 1.1 - 4.5.2 now forbid setting

> <%@ Page EnableViewStateMac="false" %>

and

> <pages enableViewStateMac="false" />

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/09/09/farewell-enableviewstatemac.aspx